how do you pick the max value of each row of certain columns in pandas
I have this data frame:
df
Node      Interface    Speed   Band_In  carrier     1-Jun            10-Jun
Server1   wan1         100     80       ATT         80               30
Server1   wan2         100     60       Sprint      60               30
Server1   wan3         100     96       Verizon     96               15

I need to create a new colum name Mx and it needs to be right after the carrier colum and it needs to only pick the max value of columns after carrier. In this case in needs to look at "1-Jun" and "10-Jun" but number of columns could be greater.
resulting df needs to looks like this:
Node      Interface    Speed   Band_In  carrier    Mx  1-Jun            10-Jun
Server1   wan1         100     80       ATT        80   80               30
Server1   wan2         100     60       Sprint     60   60               30
Server1   wan3         100     96       Verizon    96   96               15

I tried this:
df['Mx']=df.max(axis=1)

but this looks at all of the row values?
any ideas?

Get the position after "carrier" with get_loc, select the remaining columns with iloc to compute the max, then insert the output in the desired position:
# get position after "carrier" (here: 5)
n = df.columns.get_loc('carrier')+1

# select columns after that, get the max, insert after "carrier"
df.insert(n, 'Mx', df.iloc[:, n:].max(axis=1))

Updated DataFrame:
      Node Interface  Speed  Band_In  carrier  Mx  1-Jun  10-Jun
0  Server1      wan1    100       80      ATT  80     80      30
1  Server1      wan2    100       60   Sprint  60     60      30
2  Server1      wan3    100       96  Verizon  96     96      15

